# How do you write files to someone's system in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a game in batch. I want the system to save the files in a folder in the user's program files. Here's what I've got so far.

```
:FIRST_VALUES
echo set Attack=0
echo set Defense=0
echo set Magic=0
echo set Exp=0
goto save
:SAVE
(
echo set name=%plyrnm%
:DATAVALUES
echo set Attack=%Attack%
echo set Defense=%Defense%
echo set Magic=%Magic%
echo set Exp=%Exp%
)>%plyrnm%_data.bat
cls
pause>nul
```

I read about creating folders and sub-folders in another inquiry, however that person was writing to an external drive; I need it to go on the user's system, in which the directory is different for everyone. In addition, the person asking was including a "%%~D" command I didn't recognize, and thus the answers didn't make sense.

I want this to check for a game folder in the player's program files (probably x86 to give it an older feel), make one if there isn't, and then save the program to said folder. How do I do this, and are there other methods of saving other than stuffing commands in a separate batch file?

Comment: In any modern Windows version regular users aren't allowed to write into "Program Files" anyway - so if you tried, your batch file would simply fail (at least with anyone being sane enough to not run with Administrator's privileges)

Comment: could I stick it into documents, then?

Comment: or can I have it find the current directory for the game's folder, and make a "saves" subfolder there? I'd need it to check this directory and have the commands change accordingly on every startup

Comment: A "Save" directory in the same folder as the game is the traditional place to put savefiles, yes. The directory that the script is in is stored in the variable `%~dp0`.

Comment: Check out the content of the built-in environment variable `USERPROFILE` (type `echo %USERPROFILE%` into a command prompt window)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick summary of the helpful comments is as follows

-`%USERPROFILE%` is the universal term for a person's base user directory, and you can create files by sticking it into a directory command.

-`%~dp0` is the term used for the current directory of the script that executed a command with this term in it. Can be stuck in a directory command, again.

I've also found that you can use `mkdir` to make the folder in said directory.

As an example, in the game I was initially making, I can now use

```
if not exist %~0d\saves (
mkdir saves
)
```

This effectively creates a "saves" folder in whatever folder the game is in.

-I have also found that you can save and load files for a game with the `call` command. What I am using is as follows:

```
:SAVE
(
echo set name=%name%
:DATAVALUES
echo set Attack=%Attack%
echo set Defense=%Defense%
echo set Magic=%Magic%
echo set Exp=%Exp%
)>%plyrnm%_data.bat
```

The key thing to do here is to put the desired commands like this: `([commands])>[savename].bat`

When I want these values loaded, I use the `call` command, which essentially runs a batch file within another, applying all commands to the script that initially "called" it.

Thanks to everyone who helped out! I will be using these in the game!